# Create SQL Query to change SKU's from one attribute set

Tags: magento-1.9, database

Need an SQL query that I can write in PHPmyAdmin to remove all spaces in SKU for all products that have attribute set seeds (which has id 10).

For example

```
AAA 2345 EE
```

needs to be

```
AAA2345EE
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was unclear on whether you mean you're changing the skus for products that have `values set for a "seeds" attribute` or for products that use `an attribute-set called "seeds"`, so I am going to give both a try, and please let me know which one is correct.

**Case 1 | *values set for a "seeds" attribute*:**

The attribute-type is important for the "seeds" attribute, because it determines the table that is going to be used in the update statement's join.  You can find this out by running:

```
select concat('catalog_product_entity_', backend_type) 
from eav_attribute where attribute_code = 'seeds';
```

For this examples sake, lets say it is `catalog_product_entity_varchar`, in which case, trying something like this should work:

```
update catalog_product_entity cpe
join catalog_product_entity_varchar cpev
on cpe.entity_id = cpev.entiy_id 
set cpe.sku = replace(cpe.sku, ' ', '')
where cpev.attribute_id = 10
and cpev.value is not null;
```

If you want to do a "dry-run" to see which values will be changed, you can run this:

```
select cpe.sku 'Old Sku', replace(cpe.sku, ' ', '') 'New Sku'
from catalog_product_entity cpe
join catalog_product_entity_varchar cpev
on cpe.entity_id = cpev.entiy_id 
where cpev.attribute_id = 10
and cpev.value is not null;
```

**Case 2 | *an attribute-set called "seeds"*:**

This one is considerably easier because you already know the attribute_set_id is 10:

```
update catalog_product_entity
set sku = replace(sku, ' ', '')
where attribute_set_id = 10;
```

If you want to do a "dry-run" to see which values will be changed, you can run this:

```
select sku 'Old Sku', replace(sku, ' ', '') 'New Sku'
from catalog_product_entity 
where attribute_set_id = 10;
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Last one worked! The dry run didn't work, said it couldnt find cpe.sku, so I just did the run

Comment: @Sebastiaan pointed out that there were issues with the alias in the last "dry-run," and I realized no alias was needed.  The answer has been edited to correct it.